# Not Getting All Records In a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using a GoDaddy-based SQL Server 2005 to store sales from a web site. I have a `datePaid` column that is formatted as `smalldatetime`. When I query the database to display all orders for a certain date, using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    purchase.orderID, wfRegister.firstName, wfRegister.lastname, 
    storeOrder.subtotal, storeOrder.handling, storeOrder.total, 
    storeOrder.datePaid, storeOrder.dateOrdered, storeOrder.paypalID 
FROM 
    wfRegister 
INNER JOIN 
    (storeOrder INNER JOIN purchase ON storeOrder.orderID = purchase.orderID) ON wfRegister.customerID = storeOrder.customerID 
WHERE 
    storeOrder.deleted = 0 
    AND storeOrder.datePaid BETWEEN '03/21/2013' AND '03/21/2013' 
ORDER BY 
    storeOrder
```

I only get one record returned for the 21st, which is not correct. If I change the query to `storeOrder.datePaid BETWEEN '03/21/2013' AND '03/22/2013` I get 7 records returned for the 21st, which is correct, but then I also get records from the 22nd, which I don't want. Is there a way to query the datePaid field for the 21st and get all 7 records returned and not just 1? My client imports the data into Excel and does not want to have to delete the records from the 22nd to get all the records from the 21st

Comment: What data type is the column?  What do you get if you do this:  storeOrder.datePaid >= '03/21/2013' AND storeOrder.datePaid < '03/22/2013' instead of the BETWEEN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For date arithmetic in SQL Server using strings, I would recommend to always use the **ISO-8601** standard format: `YYYYMMDD` - this is the **only** format that is independent of any regional and/or language settings.

To reliably get all orders from a given day, you should use

```
AND storeOrder.datePaid >= '20130321' AND storeOrder.datePaid < '20130322'
```

The `BETWEEN` seems handy - but it's *inclusive*, e.g. you get the data from the 22nd of March, too.

This clause here gives you all records from the 21st of March, regardless of their time - but nothing from the 22nd.

Comment: For beautification purposes (and to comply with the syntax) please change backtick into apostrophe.

Comment: Many thanks on this. The ISO-8601 formatting worked and the problem is solved!